# How to pop from one view controller to another view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

Using iOS I Have 15 ViewControllers now I want to pop from one ViewController to another View Controller.

I am using this code:

```
SecondViewController *Sec=[SecondViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController popViewController:Sec animated:YES];
```

This shows error `this ViewController not exist` and then I am using this code:

```
NSArray *array = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

This code is right to pop from thirdViewController to secondViewController. But What happened when we pop from Ninth(9th)ViewController to Fifth(5th)ViewController then I am using this code in Ninth(9th)ViewController:

```
NSArray *array = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:4] animated:YES];
```

It does not pop from Ninth(9th)ViewController to Fifth(5th)ViewController apart that it pops Ninth(9th)ViewController to Eight(8th)ViewController.  I don't know what happened  when we use this line:

```
NSArray *array = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
NsLog(@"array = %@",array);
```

When we use this in `Ninth(9th)ViewController`. NsLog shows:

```
array=   First(1st)ViewController;  
         Second(2nd)ViewController;
         Eight(8th)ViewController;
         Ninth(9th)ViewController;
```

I don't know why only Four View Controllers show. Whenever I am using 15 View Controllers.  This problem occurs in each view controller.  For instance if I am Using pop form fifteenth(15th)ViewController to Fifth(5th)ViewController then same problem manifests.

```
NSArray *array = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
NsLog(@"array = %@",array);

array=     First(1st)ViewController;  
           Second(2nd)ViewController;
           fourteenth(14th)ViewController;
           fifteenth(15th)ViewController;
```

I want to count Number of ViewControllers and then pop to specific ViewController.

Comment: Are you sure sure all the ViewControllers are pushed to the NavigationController?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Swift 4.0 - Swift 5.0**

```
 for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers as Array {
            if controller.isKind(of: HomeViewController.self) {
                self.navigationController!.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
                break
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 38):

You can't pop to a new view controller (like you do with your secondViewController example).

When using a UINavigationController you

**Add Controller** to the stack with:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:<yournewViewController> animated:YES];
```

**Pop to the previous one** with :

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

**Pop to a previous controller** in the stack (Must have been pushed before) :

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:<ViewControllerToPopTo> animated:YES];
```

**Go back to the root** Controller with

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 34):

```
for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
        {
            if ([controller isKindOfClass:[nameOfYourViewControllerYouWantToNavigate class]])
            {
                [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];

                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
 [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 5):

First:

```
 SecondViewController *Sec=[SecondViewController alloc]init];
 [self.navigationController popViewController:Sec animated:YES];
```

You can’t do this because you allocate a new `Sec` view controller that’s not in a navigation controller.

Consider using this:

You are in 9 view controller

```
for (int i= 0 ; i < [[self.navigationController viewControllers]count] ; i++) {
    if ( [[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[FifiViewControllerClassname class]]) {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:i] animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
MyTableViewController *vc = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray    
arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[controllers removeLastObject];
[controllers addObject:vc];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BOOL check = FALSE;
NSArray *viewControllers = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
id obj;
for( int i=0;i<[viewControllers count];i++)
{
    obj=[viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
    if([obj isKindOfClass:[yourclassname class]])
    {
        check = TRUE;
        break;
    }
}

if (check)
{

    [[self navigationController] popToViewController:obj animated:YES];
}
else
{
    yourclassname *yourclassnameObj=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourclassStoryBoardID"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourclassnameObj animated:true];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift 3.0**, use filter:

```
let desiredViewController = self.navigationController!.viewControllers.filter { $0 is YourViewController }.first!
self.navigationController!.popToViewController(desiredViewController, animated: true)
```